# polymer - remove tap listener from light dom

Tags: polymer

i've just started web programming and have a problem with removing a tap listener added with polymer.

My component 'my-button' has a tap listener:

```
listeners: {
  tap: '_onTap'
}
```

my-buttons can be added to a my-button-group.

```
<my-button-group>
  <my-button></my-button>
  <my-button></my-button>
  ...
</my-button-group>
```

if a button was added to a my-button-group i want to remove the tap listeners of all buttons in the group.

i've tried to iterate over the groups children, but i can't find the listener in the childrens attributes/properties.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are iterating over the children with Polymer.dom(group).functions then call `node.unlisten()` to remove listener (see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base and go to the methods and the api.  You can use `this.unlisten()` if you are working within an element, but any reference to the element will work. Remember that the nodes you are working with are "distrubuted" (ie they come from the content) so you will need to use Polymer.dom(mygroup).getDistributedNodes();

Comment: inside the my-button-group the Polymer.dom(this).getDistributedNodes(); function returns an empty array. But i didn't really understand the difference between this.getEffectiveChildren() and Polymer.dom(this).getDistributedNodes()

Comment: you are right  I think getEffectiveChildren() is the correct call.  There used to be set of examples in the docs showing the difference between them but I can't find them anymore.